# Highlight Cells that don't match master list in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code. I'm looking to error check a group of cells and I'd like to highlight the ones that don't match a Master list.

```
Dim myRange, v, f, a
Set myRange = Range("P12:P200")
For Each v In Workbooks("Formula_Weighup Audit Auto-Fill Final").Worksheets("Active Master List").Range("J2:J1054")
    Set f = myRange.Find(what:=v, lookat:=xlPart)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        a = f.Address
        Do
            f.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            Set f = myRange.FindNext
        Loop While f.Address <> a
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Error: R&D #(s) do not exist" & vbNewLine & "(see highlighted items)"
Exit Sub
```

Comment: If you want to highlight the ones that *don't* match, flip the `Find` around. Loop through `myRange`, trying to find a match in the master list. If no match, highlight.

Comment: If not f Is Nothing Then

Comment: You can do this without VBA using conditional formatting. Just do a VLOOKUP on the range

Comment: If you want to highlight the ones that don't match, flip the Find around. Loop through myRange, trying to find a match in the master list. If no match, highlight. – BigBen 16 mins ago

What does flip the find around mean?

Comment: Right now you are looping through the master list - `For Each v In Workbooks...`, trying to find each individual value in `myRange`. If you want to highlight the cells in `myRange` that don't match the master list, shouldn't you loop through `myRange`? That's the "flip" I meant.

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it starts highlighting cells in my masterlist. This code is driving my insane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're looking for. Note that `rangeToCheck`, or `myRange` in your original code, is implicitly on the `ActiveSheet`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim masterWb As Workbook
    Set masterWb = Workbooks("Formula_Weighup Audit Auto-Fill Final.xlsm")
    Dim masterList As Range
    Set masterList = masterWb.Sheets("Active Master List").Range("J2:J1054")

    Dim rangeToCheck As Range
    Set rangeToCheck = Range("P12:P200")

    Dim rng As Range, found As Range

    For Each rng In rangeToCheck
        Set found = masterList.Find(what:=rng.Value, Lookat:=xlPart)
        If found Is Nothing Then rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    Next rng

    MsgBox "Error: R&D #(s) do not exist" & vbNewLine & "(see highlighted items)"

End Sub
```

EDIT: Based on comments, if you want to `Exit Sub` when a match is not found, perhaps change

```
If found is Nothing Then rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

to

```
If found is Nothing Then
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    MsgBox "Error: R&D #(s) do not exist" & vbNewLine & "(see highlighted items)"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

In regards to your comment, note that [`IF...Then...Else`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements)  has both single-line and multiple-line syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Last thing though I promise: is there anyway to attach an exit sub? I notice you have an If-Then Statement but don't end it. I didn't even know you could do that?
I'm looking to use this part of my code to say "Hey, somethings wrong. Look, it's wrong right here. Fix it and try again."
This is just a small piece of a larger body of code, so I'm getting tricky, and failing very badly along the way.

Comment: So you want to `Exit Sub` after highlighting the cell?

Comment: Yes, That is what I'd like to do. But I keep messing up trying to add to your code. If I end if and put it inbetween the if and the end if excel just tells me the Next doesn't have a for.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes!
This works perfectly, Thank you so much for your time.
I've spent 4 hours on this last little piece and I can finally present this to my boss.
You're a life saver